# How to merge two lines into one line txt file C#

Tags: c#

I have a .txt file with the following:

```
                  F    Am G F
I was tired of my lady,
            Gm7         C    E D C
We'd been together too long.
            Dm7      F     Am G F
Like a worn out recording,
     Gm7       C    E D C
of a favorite song.
```

I want to produce a txt file with the following output:

```
I was tired of my [F]lady,[Am][G][F]
We'd been toge[Gm7]ther too [C]long.[E][D][C]
Like a worn [Dm7]out recor[F]ding,[Am][G][F]
of a fa[Gm7]vorite [C]song.[E][D][C]
```

Note:

- The chords (i.e. F, Am, G, F etc.) have been inserted into the line below (it can be before or in a word; **approximate location is fine**)
- Square brackets have been added around the chords (i.e. F, Am, G, F etc.)

I am a C# developer, so I would like to use a C# library of some sort to do the above.

Comment: I am happy for some sort of guidance to be given to get me thinking of how to get an answer (in the spirit of SO)

Comment: I seriously doubt you will find a library that does this. You are going to have to roll your own.

Comment: Sorry but the *"spirit of SO"* really requires that you write some code. It won't be very hard. Use the `File` class to read the first 2 lines into 2 string (`chords` and `text`). Create a `StringBuilder` object (say `buffer`). Find the index of the first non-space character in `chords`. Get the Substring of the `text` string up to that point, and Append it to `buffer`. Get a Substring from `chords` (based on the index of the next space). Format it using *string interpolation* and Append it to buffer. Repeat to the end of the line, and then repeat for every pair of lines in the file

Comment: By the way, this will be a great way to get used to using the debugger. You can expect to be *off by one* in your index calculations pretty often. The debugger will show you how to fix that

Comment: Thanks @Flydog57 - I will give that a try and let you know.

Comment: That works. Happy for this question to be closed off or you can put your comment down as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You can answer your own question. It's Thanksgiving, I'm not going to fire up a computer and get this debugged enough to answer (those *off by one* issues affect everyone)

Answer (score 1):

As per Flydog57:

Use the File class to read the first 2 lines into 2 string (chords and text). Create a StringBuilder object (say buffer). Find the index of the first non-space character in chords. Get the Substring of the text string up to that point, and Append it to buffer. Get a Substring from chords (based on the index of the next space). Format it using string interpolation and Append it to buffer. Repeat to the end of the line, and then repeat for every pair of lines in the file

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses chord positions and lyric character positions to merge every two lines in your Lyric/Chord data.

The below class will do the work to parse the lines and merge them into
a single line with Lyrics and Chords.

```
public class LyricAndChordMerger
{
    public IList<string> MakeMergedLines(string[] lines)
    {
        IList<string> mergedLines = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i = i + 2)
        {
            string chordLine = lines[i];
            string lyricLine = lines[i + 1];
            Dictionary<int, string> chords = MakeChordsArray(chordLine);
            string mergedLine = string.Empty;            
            for (int j = 0; j < chordLine.Length; j++)
            {
                string chord = string.Empty;
                if (chords.ContainsKey(j))
                {
                    chord = chords[j] ?? "";
                    if (chord.Length > 0) chord = string.Format("[{0}]", chord);
                }
                string lyricChar = "";
                if (lyricLine.Length > j)
                {
                    lyricChar = lyricLine[j].ToString();
                }
                mergedLine += chord + lyricChar;
            }
            mergedLines.Add(mergedLine);
        }
        return mergedLines;
    }

    public Dictionary<int, string> MakeChordsArray(string chordLine)
    {
        string[] values = chordLine.Split(' ');
        Dictionary<int, string> chordsAndPositions = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        int indexOffset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
        {
            int index = i + indexOffset;
            chordsAndPositions.Add(index, values[i]);
            int valueLength = values[i].Length;
            indexOffset += valueLength <= 1 ? 0 : valueLength - 1;
        }
        return chordsAndPositions;
    }
}
```

And you would use it like so...

```
string inputFile = "[path to your lyrics and chord file]";
string[] inputLines;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(inputFile))
{
    inputLines = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[]{'\n','\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

var merger = new LyricAndChordMerger();
IList<string> mergedLines = merger.MakeMergedLines(inputLines);
foreach (string line in mergedLines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

And the output looks like...

```
I was tired of my [F]lady[Am],[G][F]
We'd been to[Gm7]gether too [C]long[E].[D][C]
Like a worn [Dm7]out reco[F]rding[Am],[G][F]
of a [Gm7]favorite [C]song[E].[D][C]
```